# copying github project into own project

Tags: objective-c, ios, github, terminal

I want to copy a github project to my own project. I did the following in my terminal

```
cd *your-project-location*
git submodule add git@github.com:escoz/QuickDialog.git
```

I gave my project folder all read and write permissions but in terminal it is giving the following error.

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Stef-2:FormsExample geelenstef$ git submodule add git@github.com:escoz/QuickDialog.git
Cloning into 'QuickDialog'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@github.com:escoz/QuickDialog.git' into submodule path 'QuickDialog' failed
```

Anybody has an idea ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the read/write access to github and so you require an SSH key set-up to allow this.  If you only want readonly access then use the `https://` URL scheme instead.

If you want to make changes to this project then you need to fork it on github and use the read/write access (`git@github...`) to access it, which as I say requires an SSH key and is beyond the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forked it on github. But what do I need to do know to install it in my project ?

Comment: @StefGeelen When I do that I create separate Xcode projects and bring them together using an Xcode Workspace.

Comment: Oké other question. What If I only one to use the project, not edit it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this to add as submudule:
git submodule add https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog